# Can the same entity be used twice in dialoglfow V2?

Tags: dialogflow-es

A number of my Intents respond to the same words - "yes" and "no".
I'm using the inline editor to handle requests/responses.
Because many of the intents respond to the same words "yes"/"no" I set up one entity called response.

So for Intent1 under the Action and parameters tab there is:

```
parameter: intent1response, entity: @response, value: $intent1response
```

For Intent2  there is:

```
parameter: intent2response, entity: @response, value: $intent2response
```

So basically i'm just changing the parameter and value for each intent but using the same entity.

But that doesn't seem to work and is messing around with contexts, etc. When I change the entity to be unique for each Intent things seem to work fine.

Just wondering if that's correct. I was also just hoping for clarification re: the input box under Actions and Parameters that says "Enter action name" - when an action name is entered here what happens with this action name in fulfilment? Can I just call it to get the parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "messing around with contexts, etc"? Can you update your question to include screen shots of the Intents and something that illustrates the problem you're having?

Comment: What I have found happening is this: Intent1 passes the user response - either yes or no - to fulfilment. In fulfilment I set the context to Intent2 so that the next user response - either yes or no - is answering Intent2...but I have found that when I use the same entity for Intent1 and Intent2 despite having set the context to Intent2, Intent1 is still being responded to. But if I change the entities and make them unique eg. response1 and response2 then I get the behaviour I expect.

Comment: This isn't the behavior I'd expect. Can you create a new question and include screen shots of the two intents in question and details of how you're testing it and what you're seeing and doing in the fulfillment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can use the same Entity in multiple Intents.

The action you specify is passed along to your fulfillment. It isn't a parameter, but is a field that is included.